# Is there any cleaner way to create a div in jQuery? I'm currently concatenating every HTML line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm looping over an array of images, creating the div that will contain all the information and then appending it to the div that will contain them. What I've done is working just fine, however, I've been wondering if there's a cleaner way to do what I'm doing right now:

```
    artworks.records.forEach((artwork, i) => {
        const record = `<div class='artwork'>` +
            `<div class='artwork-image-container'>` +
                `<img class="artwork-image" src="${artwork.images.length > 0 ? artwork.images[0].baseimageurl : './assets/no-image-available.png'}" alt="${artwork.title}" />` +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='image-description-container'>" +
                `<p class="image-description">${artwork.title}</p>`
            "</div>" +
        "</div>";
        divToBeRenderedIn.append(record);
    });
```

Comment: "template strings". you are already using it so it's very weird you did not use it around the whole block of HTML and that's it.

Comment: Alternative ways to represent HTML in your jQuery code will only go so far. You're looking for a templating library such as https://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Alternatively, you might consider [Content Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Comment: I advise you **not** to append the block of HTML at each iteration but first create a huge string block which will encompass all the items and inject it all at once.

Comment: Multiline string inserting is not the proper answer for this question.

Comment: @Dropout - `template strings` are multiline strings and they are the only correct answer. [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/805107/104380)

Comment: @vsync maybe by your standards if you intent on creating web content using strings because you just don't care about readability, scaling and maintainability of your code..

Comment: We're tilting heavily into the realm of "opinion" here

Comment: @Dropout - this is a jQuery question, and there is probably no need to import a 3rd-party templating engine just to solve this specific issue. You don't know the project's size, code structure and demands. For a "typical" jQuery-based, simple project, this is the way to go without much hassle.

Comment: Include a `display:none` div in your page when it first loads - then `.clone()` it, update any text/image src=, `.append()` it and then `.show()` it

Comment: What you stated is a common way for jQuery to display dynamic pages rendering from data. Design your own template and attached it to HTML, then use it in the loop and get result. This is already the most straightforward way if your design block is not complicated.